# AssignedAccess Windows 10 Powershell

Tags: powershell, kiosk, kiosk-mode

I am currently working on a Kiosk for my company, the point for me is to create a powershell script that will create a user and directly assign it as a Kiosk user with Microsoft Edge Chromium. It works fine with the windows settings but thats not how we need to make it. But when I want to make the command with powershell

```
Set-AssignedAccess -AUMID "MSEdge" -UserSID "USERSID"
```

When i do it this way I get this error :

```
New-CimInstance : One or multiple parameter values passed to the method are not valid.
```

So I managed to get another AUMID which is : `Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge.Stable_8wekyb3d8bbwe!App`
The command is a success after that but in the end when I connect to the Kiosk user it keeps on blinking loading blue screen and never pops out Microsoft Edge.

Does someone knows about this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this AUMID `Microsoft.MicrosoftEdge_8wekyb3d8bbwe!MicrosoftEdge`.
This works for Windows Versions below 21H2.
I cannot help you at this time with the version above 21H2.